# XML XPath for Element with Comma Delimited Text

Tags: xml, xpath, automation, nodes, element

I am trying to create the XML xPaths for specific text values contain within the string of an element.  However, the text within the element is separated by a comma, as shown below:

```
<all>
  <n0 type="dict">
    <n0 type="str">Size is 11422, 13952</n0>
  </n0>
</all>
```

If possible, I would like retrieve the xPath for both the "11422" and "13952" values (excluding "Size is") as separate xPaths, returning only the numerical values upon evaluating the xPath expression.  I believe it should look something like ".//n0[@type="str"][1]" for the "11422" value, but this does not properly delineate between the two values within the string.  Is there a concatenation I am missing?  Any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: Which version of xpath are you using?

Comment: I cannot confirm the version of xPath I am using, but I am evaluating the xPaths in Notepad++ using the XML Tools plug-in.  This plug-in has a feature to retrieve/evaluate xPaths for XML files and it works well for elements with numerical values or strings, I just don't know how to parse segments of a string value.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal xpath function for this would have been `tokenize()` (see below) but it seems Notepad++'s XML Tools don't support it.  So I believe you have to settle for this:

```
substring-before(//n0/n0,',')
```

outputs:

```
Size is 11422
```

and
substring-after(//n0/n0,',')
outputs

```
13952
```

Just FYI, had it been supported

```
tokenize(//n0/n0,',')[1]
```

and

```
tokenize(//n0/n0,',')[2]
```

would have given you the same outputs.